# c int comparrison for finish loop

Tags: c, int, do-while

I have the following function with a `do while` loop inside:

```
void GetFiveNumericValues()
{
    int validationResult;
    char input[5];
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter 5 digits:\n");
        validationResult = scanf("%s", &input);

        printf("Validation result: %d\n", validationResult);
    } while (validationResult != 1);
    // while (!(validationResult == 1));
    // while (validationResult > 1 || validationResult < 1);
}
```

The loop doesn't finish even when `validationResult == 1`.
[image: my image]
What am I missing here?

Comment: I think problem is with scanf use gets for input

Comment: it is allowed to enter as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input[]` is too small to hold a 5 character string, since it needs to hold a terminating `'\0'` in addition to the 5 input characters. If you are actually entering 5 characters then you have a buffer overflow and undefined behaviour. Change it to at least:

```
char input[6];
```

Furthermore this line:

```
validationResult = scanf("%s", &input);
```

should be:

```
validationResult = scanf("%s", input);
```

since `input` is already effectively a pointer.

Or better yet:

```
validationResult = scanf("%5s", input);
```

which will also prevent buffer overflow, even if you have invalid input.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and not only giving the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
int validationResult;
unsigned input[5];
do
{
    printf("Please enter 5 digits:\n");
    validationResult = scanf("%1u%1u%1u%1u%1u", input, input+1, input+2, input+3, input+4);
    printf("Validation result: %d\n", validationResult);
    if(validationResult != 5){
        while(getchar()!='\n');
    }
} while (validationResult != 5);
```